# How to generate dynamic rows in page based on the response of the js request? (Django Template / HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, django, dynamic, django-templates

Is this possible to append the rows with data in an HTML table as a response of the JavaScript request without doing a page postback?

**Django: 3.1.7**

I want to write a seprate HTML file (Like a file we can use with `include` tag) for the code so I don't have to append the html of entire table in the HTML string.

For now I am appending the HTML by converting to the string concatination.

**Note:** Need a solution without page postback.

```
function GetCollection(myId) {
    var Urlgetallcom = "/sc/GetCollection/" + myId ;
    // alert(Urlgetallcom);
    $.ajax({
        url: Urlgetallcom, // the endpoint
        type: "GET", // http method
        data: {
            Id: myId
        },

        // handle a successful response
        success: function (json1) {
        var groups= JSON.parse(json.Groups);
        var collection= JSON.parse(json.ftmJSON);
        $('#allTeammates').append(
        `<thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 26%;">Name</th>
                <th style="width: 30%;">Email</th>
                <th style="width: 12%;">Status</th>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Role</th>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Permission</th>
                <th style="width: 12%;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>`
        )
        for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
            var isActive = collection[i].isActive ? 'checked=checked' : ''
            var mystring1 = 
                '<tr id='+ collection[i].ftId +'>' +
                    '<td style="width: 26%;">' +
                        collection[i].name +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 30%;">' +
                        collection[i].email +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 12%;">' +
                        collection[i].status +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 20%;">' +
                        '<span class="name" value="'+collection[i].gId+'" id="lblGroups' + collection[i].fId + '">' + collection[i].gName + '</span>' +
                        '<div id="divGroups'+ collection[i].fId+ '"  style="display:none">' +
                            '<select id="dropdownList'+ collection[i].ftId + '" class="lstG" style="height: 20px;">';

                            for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
                            var sld = collection[i].gId == groups[j].pk ? 'selected=selected' : ''
                            mystring1 += '<option value="'+ groups[j].pk + '"' + sld +' > '
                            + g[j].f.name+' </option>'
                            }
                            mystring1 += '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 20%;">' +
                        '<input id="chkIsActive'+ collection[i].ftId+ '" type="checkbox" '+ isActive +' disabled >' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width: 12%;">' +
                        '<div id="EditDelete'+ collection[i].ftId+ '">' +
                            '<button type=button style="background-color:#0d7458;border-color:#0d7458;" onclick="editFTeams('+ collection[i].ftId+ ')">' +
                                '<img src="/static/images/Icons/edit-icon.svg" width="12" height="12">' +
                            '</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div id="UpdateSave'+ collection[i].ftId+ '" style="display:none">' +
                            '<button type=button style="background-color:#0d7458;border-color:#0d7458;" onclick="UpdateTeams('+ collection[i].ftId+ ')" >' +
                            '<img src="/static/images/Icons/save.svg" width="12" height="12"/>' +
                            '</button>' +

                            '<button type=button style="background-color:#0d7458;border-color:#0d7458;" onclick="CancelFTeams('+ collection[i].ftId+ ')" >' +
                            '<img src="/static/images/Icons/cancel.svg" width="12" height="12"/>' +
                            '</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>'
            $('#allTeams').append(mystring1)        },
        complete: function (response) {
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: " + errmsg +
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: 1. You are not creating a table - 2. If you do need to create a table, have you considered using DataTables (js) which conveniently has a Django package compatible with DRF?

Comment: 1- Sorry, I put the wrong code by mistake. Updated the code in question.
2- Never heard of this before, even if I use the DataTables of js, again I have to append the rows. Maybe I am not understanding your suggestion. Can you please pass me an example or a link? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [django-rest-framework-datatables](https://django-rest-framework-datatables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - here you can leverage the DataTable js library and DRF to build dynamic tables on the front end.

Per the docs, you can use this simple js code to build a DataTable provided you have a DRF endpoint set up. This comes with all the advantages of paging, ordering, searching, filtering, etc and, in my opinion, is more dynamic than the built in Django-admin pages.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#albums').DataTable({
    'serverSide': true,
    'ajax': '/api/albums/?format=datatables',
    'columns': [
      {'data': 'rank'},
      {'data': 'artist.name', 'name': 'artist.name'},
      {'data': 'name'},
      {'data': 'year'},
      {'data': 'genres', 'name': 'genres.name'},
    ]
  });
});
```

Let me know if you need more details.

For more on DataTables check out the docs [here](https://datatables.net/).

Comment: Will this approach works the same even if I am not using the DRF? Because I am calling my own views from the js instead of the API method of DRF.

Comment: You can set `serverSide` to false, change the `ajax` url to your own custom url, and return the results in a DataTable-friendly format. However you would lose a lot of the power of DataTables and DRF.

Comment: Is this possible to call the DRF API from within my own solution? 
My DRF and my Django App is in the same project (2 apps in same project).

Comment: Yes - you can all any DRF endpoint.